# Odoo: get type of field by name

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

in odoo you can get value of field by it's str name:
exm:

```py
  name = getattr(self, 'name')
```

what i want now is to know the type of field name is it :

```py
fields.Char, fields.Many2one, fields.Many2many .....
```

so what i need is something like this

```py
 gettype(self, 'user_id')
```

is there a way to now what is the type of field in odoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odoo provides this information in the `_fields` attribute, I think It's better because every thing happens In the `Python` side no need for contacting the database, especially In my case my model have more than `30` fields :

```py
 for name, field in self._fields.iteritems():
      if not isinstance(field, (fields.Many2one, fields.Many2many, fields.One2many)):
           # logic go here
```

If you you want to verify just one fields:

```py
  if not isinstance(self._fields[field_name], (fields.Many2one, ...)):  # do something
```

Answer (score 5):

You can search from **ir.model.fields** model.

```
ir_model_obj=self.env['ir.model.fields']
ir_model_field=ir_model_obj.search([('model','=',model),('name','=',field)])
field_type=ir_model_field.ttype
if field_type=='many2one':
    print "do operation"
```

This may help you.